# SQL - Resolving a Circular Loop

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently trying to create a database for tracking the materials for crafts in an mmorpg, and have come across the following loop I'm struggling to resolve:

There are Ingredients, which are used to in Recipes to create new items, however, an item created by a Recipe may also be an ingredient.

I have currently got a database with 3 tables: Items, Recipes and RecipeLink.

Each record in item has a name, amount acquired by the user, and some other information about the item.

Each record in Recipe has a name (which currently may also appear in Item, if it is also used as an Item), The amount of the item it creates, A boolean (Yes/No field as I am using MS Access) for whether or not this item has been crafted, and some other information as to the skill requirements of the craft.

Each record in RecipeLink connects an Item required to a Recipe it is used to create and the quantity required for it.

e.g.

Item:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Acquired:** 586; **Details:** Mined or found in Elementals
- **Item:** Logs; **Acquired:** 12; **Details:** Cut from trees

Recipe:

- **Name:** Planks;** **Quantity:** 3; **Crafted:** True; **Details:** Requires carpentry level 7

RecipeLink:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Recipe:** Planks; **Quantity:** 7
- **Item:** Logs; **Recipe:** Planks; **Quantity:** 3

The query I am currently using would return:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Acquired:** 586; **TotalRequired:** 0;
- **Item:** Logs; **Acquired:** 12; **TotalRequired:** 0; (as planks is already crafted, so the 3 logs for it aren't needed)

However, the issues arises when planks are required for other crafts:

Item:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Acquired:** 586; **Details:** Mined or found in Elementals
- **Item:** Logs; **Acquired:** 12; **Details:** Cut from trees
- **Item:** Planks; **Acquired:** 2; **Details:** Made from logs

Recipe:

- **Name:** Planks; **Quantity:** 3; **Crafted:** True; **Details:** Requires carpentry level 7
- **Name:** WoodenBowl; **Quantity:** 1; **Crafted:** True; **Details:** Requires carpentry level 11
- **Name:** Bow; **Quantity:** 1; **Crafted:** False; **Details:** Requires carpentry level 15
- **Name:** Bench; **Quantity:** 1; **Crafted:** False; **Details:** Requires carpentry level 22

RecipeLink:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Recipe:** Planks; **Quantity:** 7
- **Item:** Logs; **Recipe:** Planks; **Quantity:** 3
- **Item:** EarthShards; **Recipe:** WoodenBowl; **Quantity:** 6
- **Item:** Planks; **Recipe:** WoodenBowl; **Quantity:** 3
- **Item:** EarthShards; **Recipe:** Bow; **Quantity:** 16
- **Item:** Planks; **Recipe:** Bow; **Quantity:** 5
- **Item:** EarthShards; **Recipe:** Bench; **Quantity:** 38
- **Item:** Planks; **Recipe:** Bench; **Quantity:** 12

My current query would return:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Acquired:** 586; **TotalRequired:** 54;
- **Item:** Logs; **Acquired:** 12; **TotalRequired:** 0; (as planks is already crafted, so the 3 logs for it aren't needed)
- **Item:** Planks; **Acquired:** 2; **TotalRequired:** 17; (as the 3 for the wooden bowl are not needed as the wooden bowl is already crafted.)

However I want it to return:

- **Item:** EarthShards; **Acquired:** 586; **TotalRequired:** 89;
- **Item:** Logs; **Acquired:** 12; **TotalRequired:** 15; (as 3 are needed per plank, and 15 extra planks are needed)
- **Item:** Planks; **Acquired:** 2; **TotalRequired:** 17;

The main issue is, I think it is possible to make a query to do this with simply two levels of a recipe-created-item being used in another recipe. However in the game there are some crafts that have more than just two levels, i.e.
logs -> used to make planks -> used to make strengthenedPlanks -> used to make a strongBow -> used to make an enchantedStrongBow -> used to make an apocalypseBow

It is possible that future game updates will create crafts that have even longer chains than the example above.

How should I create a database (or query, if it is possible with my current database) to manage this?

Please tell me if/what extra information would be useful to resolve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking everything craftable or not, should be represented in Item table.

**Item:**

- ItemId: 1; Name: EarthShards
- ItemId: 2; Name: Logs
- ItemId: 3; Name: Planks
- ItemId: 4; Name: WoodenBowl

Recipes should exist for craft-able items. Each recipe should reference the item it creates. You may chose not to even have a **Name** property because you can get the name from the OutputItemId.

**Recipe:**

- RecipeId 1; Name: Planks; OutputItemId: 3; OutputQuantity: 3
- RecipeId 2; Name: WoodenBowl; OutputItemId: 4; OutputQuantity: 1

RecipeLink would be unchanged from the way you currently have it. It ties a recipe to the necessary items and their quantity.

**RecipeLink:**

- RecipeId: 1; ItemId: 1; Quantity: 7
- RecipeId: 1; ItemId: 2; Quantity: 3
- RecipeId: 2; ItemId: 1; Quantity: 6
- RecipeId: 2; ItemId: 3; Quantity: 3

Once you have this setup, you need to do some recursive querying. You would start with the items directly reqired by the recipe that is being crafted. For each of those items get the Recipe by join to OutputItemId, then get the items for that recipe, so on and so forth.

I understand you are using MS Access. It seems like the best way to do this sort of recusive query is to write a function in Access. This article explains what to do: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132242/EN-US

I'm not sure if you are willing to consider other databases for your development like Sql Server Express or Sql LocalDb. Both are free and would give you more querying horsepower.

I created a SqlFiddle to show you how you can get the results you want in either of those Sql products with a single query. Check it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18071/3

Comment: Thanks for this, it has all the information I need, just need to understand SQL and VB a whole lot more to adapt it to what I have, although at least I know where I'm going with it now!